# Reading XML file using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have tried to read XML file using Linq. Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinqToXml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"E:\\XML\\test.xml");
            xdoc.Descendants("Title").Select(t => new
            {
            fontType = t.Attribute("fontType").Value,
            fontSize = t.Attribute("fontSize").Value,
            fontColor = t.Attribute("fontColor").Value,
            Underline = t.Attribute("Underline").Value,
            Bold = t.Attribute("Bold").Value,
            Italic = t.Attribute("Italic").Value,
        }).ToList().ForEach(t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("fontType : " + t.fontType);
            Console.WriteLine("fontSize : " + t.fontSize);
            Console.WriteLine("fontColor : " + t.fontColor);
            Console.WriteLine("Underline : " + t.Underline);
            Console.WriteLine("Bold : " + t.Bold);
            Console.WriteLine("Italic : " + t.Italic);
        });

        Console.ReadLine();

       }
     }
  }
```

It gives an below exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in programm.exe

But I can't find what is the error. Can anyone help me..

This is the XML file which I have used..

```
   <Styles>
   <Title>
    <fontType>TimesNewRoman</fontType>
    <fontSize>20</fontSize>
    <fontColor>black</fontColor>
    <Underline>No</Underline>
    <Bold>bold</Bold>
    <Italic>No</Italic>
  </Title>
  <Title>
    <fontType>TimesNewRoman</fontType>
    <fontSize>20</fontSize>
    <fontColor>black</fontColor>
    <Underline>No</Underline>
    <Bold>bold</Bold>
    <Italic>italic</Italic>
  </Title>
</Styles>
```

Comment: you need to show the XML you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any `fontType`, `fontSize`, etc. attributes on the `Title` element. `fontType`, `fontSize` are elements, so you should use

```
fontType = t.Element("fontType").Value
```